# forticlientssl-vpn_cli end before verification token is passed using expect

Tags: bash, expect, vpn

I would like to automate login to my VPN with forticlient. I automatically pass password with `expect` command. After right password I receive verification token but before I write it to console, the script ends. This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/expect << EOF
spawn /opt/forticlient-sslvpn/64bit/forticlientsslvpn_cli --server server.com:443 --vpnuser user --keepalive
expect "Password for VPN:"
send "MyPaSsWoRd\r"
expect "Would you like to connect to this server? (Y/N)"
send "Y\r"
expect "A FortiToken code is required for SSL-VPN login authentication."
expect EOF
```

How can I read Token from stdin, or is there better way how to solve this issue? Is there a way how to create some configuration file where will be server address, user, password, etc and insert it to forticlient_cli?

Comment: `expect eof` in lower case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not to solve my porblem with `expect` so I used python3 lib [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). This is my result which works fine:

```
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn('/opt/forticlient-sslvpn/64bit/forticlientsslvpn_cli --server server.com:443 --vpnuser user --keepalive', encoding='utf-8')
child.expect('Password for VPN:')
child.sendline('PaSsWoRd')
child.expect('Would you like to connect to this server\? \(Y\/N\)')
child.sendline('Y')

child.interact()
child.kill(1)
print('is alive:', child.isalive())
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say "the script ends", I assume it times out after about 20 seconds

This is what I *think* you're asking:

```
expect "A FortiToken code is required for SSL-VPN login authentication."
send_user "Enter the token: "
gets stdin token
send -- "$token\r"
# then, you interact with the connection ...
```

Comment: Hi, set `expect eof` to lower case and add your code. It not work. Now it ends immediatelly with `NOTICE::Insufficient credential(s). Please check the password, client certificate, etc` error. But when I use commands from script in bash, it works fine.